# When are abelian categories $\operatorname{mod-}R$ and $\operatorname{mod-}\operatorname{End}_R(M) $ equivalent?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, equivalence-of-categories

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian integral domain. Let $M$ be a finitely generated projective $R$-module of positive rank. Are the abelian categories $\operatorname{mod-}R$ and $\operatorname{mod-}\operatorname{End}_R(M) $ equivalent ?

Comment: Have you ever read about Morita theory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence

Comment: Have you tried looking at the case $R=k$ a field? this would give the category of vector spaces equivalent to the category of $\operatorname{End}(k^2)$- modules are equiv. Also this looks like morita equivalences between your rings

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Pedro thanks I don't remember my lessons very well haha